# Python: Overwrite a function/method with the content of a String

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

As said in the title, I want to overwrite a function/method with the content of a string.

**Background**

I want to use an extern library which handles a CNN-model. The problem is, that some of these models contain functions, which my library cant handle. So I investigated the structure of the model and found out that some layers contain operators like "+=", which my extern library can't handle, so I have to replace these lines every time I found them.

To realize this, I used the **inspect** module to generate the a string, which contains the function with the problematic lines.

Out of this string a generate an abstract syntax tree with the **ast** module.

In this structure I could change the function like I needed it.

Now I can parse this abstract syntax tree to a string if needed, but the problem is that a lot of techniques to transform this string into a function, so that I can overwrite the problematic functions with my generated code in the string, but I failed every time.

This is my code in the moment, and sorry for the bad style, I'm a neewby to that :(

```
import torchvision
import torch
import inspect
import textwrap
import ast
from pprint import pprint

import torch.nn as nn

# This is a model which i have to investigate
model = torchvision.models.resnet18()

# Here i extract all classes and functions to check them below
classes = [
    x[0] for x in inspect.getmembers(nn, inspect.isclass)
]

# This class changed my abstract syntax tree into the form i need
class Trasformer(ast.NodeTransformer):

    def visit_AugAssign(self,node):
        return (ast.Assign(targets=[ast.Name(id='out', ctx=ast.Store())], value=ast.Call(func=ast.Attribute(value=ast.Name(id='torch', ctx=ast.Load()), attr='stack', ctx=ast.Load()), args=[ast.List(elts=[ast.Name(id='identity', ctx=ast.Load()), ast.Name(id='out', ctx=ast.Load())], ctx=ast.Load())], keywords=[ast.keyword(arg='dim', value=ast.UnaryOp(op=ast.USub(), operand=ast.Constant(value=1)))])), ast.Assign(targets=[ast.Name(id='out', ctx=ast.Store())], value=ast.Call(func=ast.Attribute(value=ast.Name(id='self', ctx=ast.Load()), attr='canonizer_sum', ctx=ast.Load()), args=[ast.Name(id='out', ctx=ast.Load())], keywords=[])))

# This function checks, if there
def recursive(model):
    children = list(model.children())
    print(f"Checking {model.__class__.__name__}\t{len(children)}")

    if len(children) == 0:
        # print(model)
        pass

    else:
        if not model.__class__.__name__ in classes:
            # print(model)
            print(f"!!{model.__class__.__name__}")
            print(textwrap.dedent(inspect.getsource(model.forward)))

            """Hier wird der Code der Funktion verändert"""
            forward_code = textwrap.dedent(inspect.getsource(model.forward))
            tree = ast.parse(forward_code)
            #print(ast.dump(tree))
            # Using the Transformer class, to visit all nodes in the abstract syntax tree, and if the node is "AugAssign (+=) then the node will changed into two nodes, with the correct statements
            Trasformer().visit(tree)

            # delivers the needed information of the new nodes, after the change
            tree = ast.fix_missing_locations(tree)
            # print(ast.dump(tree, indent=2))

            # Here the changed AST is compiled into string
            forward_code = ast.unparse(tree)
            """Up to this point everything works fine. But now the problems start."""

            #At this point i tried different ways to  overwrite the function "model.forward" which the function, hold in the string. But nothing worked. This is my last attempt 

            model.forward. = exec(compile(tree, filename='test', mode='exec'))
            # here the first line of code is cut off, (the function definition, because just the code inside should be overwritten
            # forward_code = forward_code.split("\n", 1)[1] 
            print("new string:\n")
            #print(forward_code)
            print(textwrap.dedent(inspect.getsource(model.forward)))

            # TODO: Transform the string into the method -> i.e. overwrite the method is needed"""
            # setattr(model,"forward", forward_code)

            #print("new:\n")
            #print(textwrap.dedent(inspect.getsource(model.forward)))

        for module in children:
            recursive(module)


recursive(model)

quit()
```

So my question is, is it possible to overwrite a function/method with the content of a string?

I had different ideas:

- Overwrite it directly --> doesn't  work because you can't assign a string to a function
- Write the string into a file and load the content of the file into the function

  - I haven't tried it yet, because I thought that there has to be a better way.
- use exec/eval/compile. I think this way it maybe could work but I  have no idea how.

  - I tried it with the function head in the string and without in it

Could somebody please help me and tell me how I overwrite the function with a corrected ast tree or the string generated out of it?

Is there a module/ function from the python library which I could use?

Thanks in advance for all volunteer helpers :)

Answer (score 0):

Python functions are *immutable*, like many other Python objects. Once created, you cannot modify a function. But you can normally replace it with a different function, by setting the attribute of the class or object from which the function was extracted.

By the way, if you have the AST of a function, there is no need to turn it into a string in order to compile it. You can just compile the AST itself.

Comment: Hello and Thank you very much for your Answer :)

So, if i understand you right, there is no chance for me to overwrite the function with my ast?

So i have to compile the AST into executable code with **eval/exec/compile**, right?
But the problem is, that i can't overwrite the function with it.

Can you please tell me how i can replace the original function, by setting the attribute of the class from which the function came originally?
I'm a little confused here and I'm not sure exactly what you mean:(

Thank you :-)

Comment: @balticFoo: I really don't know what you're trying to do, but it looks to me like you're trying to replace the `forward` member function of objects of certain classes. That function is an attribute of the class, so you can replace it using something like `setattr(model.__class__, 'forward', new_func)`. You might want to reread the description of how Oython classes work.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This looks promising to me.

And you're right. In my usecase i recheive a class which can contain a function 'forward'. And it is possible that in this function there is an assign with "+=", which another module cant handle later.

So  i have to check the module classes and if i found a forward with "+=", i have to replace it.

But i've another question.
I changed the function by using AST, and now i have an ast or a string. 
But in  _setattr(...**new_func**)_ i need a function. Can i use my ast there? Isn't it the same problem? or am i too stupidto understand?

Comment: @baltic: there's one small complication. I'll write it up a bit later

Comment: Thank your very much for your help:)
In the moment it is possible for me to compile the ast and give it to setattr
`tree_code_object = compile(tree, filename='<ast>', mode='exec')
`setattr(model.__class__, "forward", tree_code_object)`

But now i have the problem that i cant check the code of the function because it is compiled code. I'm not sure if i did it right. My recursive function didn't work anymore, when the function, to be edited, is overwritten with the compiled ast
I look forward to your anwser :)

Comment: Because know, i get an **OSError: could not get source code** when i call `print(textwrap.dedent(inspect.getsource(model.forward)))`, probably because inspect cant get the code, because the function is now a piece of compiled code 

Maybe this is important for you:
Thank you very much @rici :)